# ASP.NET Core Razor page URL rewrite middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Would like some assistance rewriting/redirecting to a new URL. I have an area in the razor application called dashboard.

The dashboard can be accessed when there is a valid tenant:

```
http://localhost:5001/ValidTenant/Dashboard
```

URL would allow the user to navigate to the dashboard area.

The following URLs would not be valid

```
http://localhost:5001/Dashboard
http://localhost:5001/InValidTenant/Dashboard
```

The 1st invalid url should be redirected to my error page, while the second url should be redirected to a `refer.cshtml` page.

A little background I am using a multitenant solution called [Finbuckle](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant) and I am using the "Base Path" [strategy](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant/Docs/v6.12.0/Strategies#base-path-strategy) to resolve a tenant.

I have a little piece of middleware attempting to match the invalid urls and redirect them, albeit without much luck.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var tenant = context.GetMultiTenantContext<AppTenantInfo>();
    
    // If tenant can't be resolved, proceed with URL redirection
    if (tenant is null)
    {    
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect(@"^dashboard/(.*)", "/error=?statusCode=404")
        .AddRedirect(@"(.*)/dashboard/(.*)", "refer");

        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});

app.Run();
```

I have been trying to follow the documentation here without luck.

[URL rewriting middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

I can get the following piece of code to work which interrupts the request and redirects, but I would rather follow the guidelines in the link above.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var tenant = context.GetMultiTenantContext<AppTenantInfo>();

    // If tenant can't be resolved, proceed with URL redirection
    if (tenant is null)
    {
        var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (url is not null && url.Contains("dashboard"))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/refer");
            return;
        }
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});

app.Run();
```

Any help appreciated.